# How to change or add text color of road.highway when styling google maps API V3

Tags: json, google-maps, styles

I'm trying to style the map but the text is not visible http://joxi.ru/RmzoN4DFR00d82. I need to display white text on it. This is what I'm trying but no luck

```
     {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#FFFFFF"
          }
       ]
     }
```

Comment: What you have here should work. Can you set up an [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Google's [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). To change the text color of highway road labels you can use the style below as an example:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#a1a1a1"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

From what I see in your screenshot, the issue may be that you are adding color to the icons and hence overriding the text content within it (which cannot be styled). So make sure you avoid this as per the above code.

Hope this helps you!